# Which iOS font supports Unicode Math Alphanumeric Symbols 0001D400

Tags: ios, iphone, unicode

There is a category of Unicode characters that I want to use on iOS (must be unicode). Unfortunately none of the built-in iOS fonts support these characters (tested and proven. Other unicode characters work). How can I get this grouping of Unicode characters to work on iOS? These characters must be supported in the native text messaging app (iOS 8)

I've posted an image of the category as shown in the Character View on MAC OSX

Here is an example of one such character:

MATHEMATICAL BOLD SCRIPT CAPITAL D
Unicode: U+1D4D3 (U+D835 U+DCD3), UTF-8: F0 9D 93 93, GB: 94339F33

[image]

Comment: The Unicode character `\U1D4D3` seems to be in all iOS fonts. How did you test and determine it's not there?

Comment: \U0001D4D3 does not show the character - it shows an "alien head" inside of a box